# OOXML - Linq to Extract Word Tables With a Certain Caption

Tags: c#, linq, openxml

I'm using the Open XML SDK 2.6 to try & update a Word Document. I can use the <w:tblCaption> element to identify a table.  My question is, what Linq query do I need to use to get a reference to entire <w:tbl> structure, given             a table with a certain <w:tblCaption> w:val attribute?

```
DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(@"D:\dev\openxml\table.docx", false);


var tables = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Descendants<Table>().ToList();

//WHAT LINQ STATEMENT DO I USE?
```

**DOCX TBL XML**

```
    <w:tbl>
        <w:tblPr>
            <w:tblW w:w="4814" w:type="dxa"/>
            <w:tblInd w:w="247" w:type="dxa"/>
            <w:tblBorders>
                <w:top w:val="single" w:sz="4" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
                <w:left w:val="single" w:sz="4" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
                <w:bottom w:val="single" w:sz="4" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
                <w:right w:val="single" w:sz="4" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
                <w:insideH w:val="single" w:sz="4" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
                <w:insideV w:val="single" w:sz="4" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
            </w:tblBorders>
            <w:tblLayout w:type="fixed"/>
            <w:tblLook w:val="0000" w:firstRow="0" w:lastRow="0" w:firstColumn="0" w:lastColumn="0" w:noHBand="0" w:noVBand="0"/>
            <w:tblCaption w:val="TBL_TEST"/>
        </w:tblPr>
        <w:tblGrid>
            <w:gridCol w:w="1468"/>
            <w:gridCol w:w="1444"/>
            <w:gridCol w:w="1902"/>
        </w:tblGrid>
        <w:tr>
        </w:tr>
 </w:tbl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
XDocument doc;
XNamespace ns = 
    XNamespace.Get(@"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main");

using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(stream, true))
{
  using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(doc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream()))
  using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(sr))
     xdoc = XDocument.Load(xr);

  XElement table;
  //Descendants() gets all children,grandchildren etc.
  //First get document -> body ->
  XElement tablecapt = xdoc.Elements().First().Elements().First()
                           .Descendants().Where(d => d.Name == XName.Get("tblCaption", ns) 
                                                && d.Value == "TBL_TEST").FirstOrDefault();

   if (tablecapt != null)
     table = tablecapt.Parent.Parent;
}
```

I can't test it at the moment, but I think it shouldn't be too far off.